# Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that your installed application is debuggable?

Tags: android, c, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm using eclipse to debug my android app which has a c native code.

When i plug in my nexsus4 the ndk external debugging tool works.

when I plug my galaxy note2 it throws the following error when trying to attach to the device:

```
Android NDK installation path: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/android-ndk-r8b
Using specific adb command: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
Using ADB flags: 
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: com.myPack
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
Device API Level: 18
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
Found debuggable flag: true
Found device gdbserver: /data/data/com.myPack/lib/gdbserver
ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that
       your installed application is debuggable?
```

I have enabled developers options

and allowed device debugging via usb

it doesn't work for my samsung galaxy note2 (android 4.3) but works for nexsus4 (4.2)

I think this is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373)?

but how to workarround this?

Comment: It may help to restart adb as root. First enable the behavior in developer options, then run adb root from your desktop. The ndk-gdb script in particular needs root permissions on my phone to find information about the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with Android 4.3 in general.  Take a look at the Android bug tracker issue [59558](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59558) which in turn links to the root of the issue that run-as is borked. ([58373](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373))  I'm not sure when/if the Note 2 is getting 4.4, so you may want to look into whether or not you can downgrade back to 4.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

> This happens due to two known bugs related to the run-as tool. The tool needs to read information about your app from the /data/system/packages.list file inside your Android device. In the case of the first bug, the tool is actually only reading the first 8KB of the file. Thus, if the line containing your app description is below the first 8 KB, run-as will fail. The second bug affects some 4.2.2 and 4.3 Android images by falsely restricting read rights of the packages.list file that contains all the package names.

Solution here: http://visualgdb.com/KB/?ProblemID=nopkg

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had rooted my Android 2.3 device and changed the default shell to be bash, which was causing issues when ndk-gdb tried to run a shell command.

```
sh-3.2$ ls -l /system/bin/sh*
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2014-02-01 10:26 sh -> bash
-rwsr-xr-x root     shell       82840 2011-09-30 18:55 sh0
sh-3.2$
```

This was causing the android r9 ndk-gdb script to abort with that 'Could not extract package data directory..' error.

Make a backup copy of your ndk-gdb script first.
Then, near line 615 of ndk-gdb, make the following edits:

```
# Find the <dataDir> of the package on the device
# on my rooted Android 2.3 device, the default sh has   actually been renamed to sh0
# so try that first.
adb_var_shell2 DATA_DIR run-as $PACKAGE_NAME /system/bin/sh0 -c pwd  # <-- insert this line
if [ $? != 0 ]  # <-- insert this line
then # <-- insert this line
    adb_var_shell2 DATA_DIR run-as $PACKAGE_NAME     /system/bin/sh -c pwd
    if [ $? != 0 -o -z "$DATA_DIR" ] ; then
        echo "ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that"
        echo "       your installed application is debuggable?"
        exit 1
    fi
fi  # <-- insert this line
```

Basically, it will try to use /system/bin/sh0 first. If the file doesn't exist, then it will then try /system/bin/sh. I've only tested the /system/bin/sh0 case so far, so YMMV..